# Keras validation loss

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

In training keras/tensorflow networks I observe losses in validation datasets much lower than in training datasets - by orders of magnitude. I am using the adam optimizer and mean_squared_error loss. The behavior is consistent over different network types and dataset sizes. I would expect mean loss in validation to greater than in train. Perhaps mean_squared_error is erroneously absolute squared error, which could account for lower values since validation is typically smaller than train? If not then what explains this behavior?

Comment: What is your train / test split size?

Comment: Train / test split is variable; effect persisted regardless of the split. Per braaterAfrikaaner's suggestion below, I changed from data normalization to standardization. Normalization was bad due to outliers. With standardized data the behavior is much improved. Test loss is still lower than Train but now same order of magnitude. I attribute the remaining difference to the average-over-epoch effect described by braaterAfrikaaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in part due to the fact that training error for an epoch is computed as an average over batches of training data, while validation error is computed at the end of the epoch for the entire validation set. Since training makes progress within an epoch, training error over the first batches is typically higher than over the last batches. It should not make a difference of orders of magnitude though.

It could be that your training and validation data are fundamentally different, or that you haven't preprocessed the data correctly. Make sure you standardize your data. Moreover, if you are not working with timeseries, randomly shuffle your dataset before you split into train/val set.